# Computing $A^{30}$ using eigenvectors and change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $$ A = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$ Find an invertible matrix $S$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $ A = SDS^{-1}$. Compute $A^{30}$.

I found the diagonal matrix $D$ to be $$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_1 \\ -x_1 & x_1 \end{bmatrix} $$ I find the problem as a whole quite confusing though, and Im not sure how to find $S$ and $S^{-1}$ and put it all together.

Comment: What is $x_1$? Of course, if $A=SDS^{-1}$ then $A^n=SD^nS^{-1}$.

Comment: This is not a [diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix).  A diagonal matrix has only zeroes off the main diagonal.

Comment: Your title mentions eigenvectors.  How do you find the eigenvectors (and the eigenvalues)?

Comment: Do your self a favour and read what your textbook has to say about diagonalizing a matrix.

Comment: @EricTowers from what i understand the diagonal matrix is a matrix where the columns are the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eigenvalues: $k_1=3,k_2=1$. Eigenvectors: $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Symmetric matrix:
$$D=S^{-1}AS=\begin{pmatrix} \frac12 & \frac12 \\ \frac12 & -\frac12\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
$$A^{30}=SD^{30}S^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{3^{30}+1}{2} & \frac{3^{30}-1}{2} \\ \frac{3^{30}-1}{2} & \frac{3^{30}+1}{2}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: How did you figure out the eigenvectors? We have $x_1 = x_2$ for $k_1 = 3$, and $x_1 = -x_2$ for $k_2 = 1$, respectively. Couldn't you also have used something like $$\begin{bmatrix} 43 \\ 43 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -64 \\ 64 \end{bmatrix}$$ for the eigenvectors?

Comment: @Pame, yes, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250121/conceptual-question-about-equivalence-of-eigenvectors

Comment: Just so we're clear, you multiply $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3^{30} \\ 1 & -3^{30} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\frac12 & \frac 12 \\ \frac12 & \frac{-1}{2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{3^{30}+1}{2} & \frac{3^{30}-1}{2} \\ \frac{3^{30}-1}{2} & \frac{3^{30}+1}{2}\end{bmatrix} $$ or did i go wrong somewhere? I calculated $SD$ for the first matrix.

Comment: $SD^{30}S^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\ 1&-1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 3^{30} & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}S^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 3^{30} & -1 \\ 3^{30} &-1 \end{pmatrix} S^{-1}=...$

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (but not only) matrices would be $D = \Lambda$, the diagonal matrix containing zeros on the off-diagonals and the eigenvalues of $A$ on its diagonal, and $S$ is a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Are there infinitely many matrices $S$ since there are infinitely many eigenvectors?

Comment: Due to scaling, yes.